# Effect of missing segments on outcome variable in time series

Tags: time-series, missing-data, generalized-additive-model

Intuitively this is the case of something that exists but I don't know what it is called and so can't google it.

I have time series data in which some data are randomly missing. I suspect that, due to the nature of the data collected, segments directly after missing data will differ from the mean. I want to include this in my analysis. I use Generalised Additive Modelling.

(I have pupil dilation data from babies watching one of two videos. Video A contains information that is harder to process than Video B. You expect, for various neurophysiological reasons, a more dilated pupil for Video A than for Video B. However, Video B is more boring (for practically unrelated reasons). Since you can't tell babies what to do, they will get bored and look outside the screen more often. Outside the screen is black, so their pupils will dilate. This is a confound.)

Currently I use a total tally of % data missing in each time series. But this is a grossly simplifying measure.

Answer (score 0):

For the unfiltered data (where missing observations are still marked) I calculated a rolling average of whether an observation is missing or not. I used the rollmean() function in the zoo package (link1).

I used data on the speed of pupillary reactions of neurotypical infants in the age range of my study to determine the window for the rolling average (link2).

Rolling averages in the filtered data still indicate whether a large amount of data were just missing or not. I can use this trajectory and compare it with the trajectory of pupil dilation. Maybe.

https://www.storybench.org/how-to-calculate-a-rolling-average-in-r/

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6985190/